# Winform how to change the way that resize calling the repaint event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small Form to paint a grid. But when I resize it, which I mean drag the edge of the form, there is something wrong with my grid. below is the image:[image]

As you can see, the form is keep repainting it when I hold the mouse button. I think I can fix the problem by change the way the resize event call the repaint event. Is there anyway that the repaint event only be called after I release the mouse button?

Here is the snap code of how I draw the grid:

```
 private void PictureBox_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        viewsizeX = pictureBox.Width;
        viewsizeY = pictureBox.Height;
        cellSizeX = 50;
        cellSizeY = 50;
        numOfCellsX = (viewsizeX - (viewsizeX % cellSizeX)) / cellSizeX;
        numOfCellsY = (viewsizeY - (viewsizeY % cellSizeY)) / cellSizeY;


        // draw horizontal lines of gird
        for (int y = 0; y <= numOfCellsY; ++y)
        {
            g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, y * cellSizeY, viewsizeX, y * cellSizeY);
        }
        // draw vertical lines of gri， +6 because here we are drawing 6 more lines on the right of the grid for further moving.
        for (int x = 1; x <= numOfCellsX * 2; ++x)
        {
            int position = (x * cellSizeX) + changeValue;
            if (position >= 0 && position <= viewsizeX)
            {
                g.DrawLine(bgp, position, 0, position, viewsizeY);
            }
        }
```

My event list :
[image]

Comment: You can set `this.ResizeRedraw = false;`  (or `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, false);`) and `Invalidate()` in `OnResizeEnd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respond to the ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd events. As in:

```
private disablePaint = false;

private void MyForm_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    disablePaint = true;
}

private void MyForm_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    disablePaint = false;
}

private void PictureBox_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    if (disablePaint) return;

    // your paint code here
}
```

Do not paint while resizing is in progress.  Note the use of the `disablePaint` flag.